# Using @ inside href of anchor tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, href, razorengine

I have implemented a simple payment gateway, the payment url has `@` in it, as shown below:

```
<a href="https://www.somegateway.com/@john_doe/" class="im-checkout-btn btn--light" target="_blank" rel="modal">Checkout With someGateway</a>
```

This is an ASP.NET MVC web application, so the view is Razor view engine, and it is not accepting `@` inside the href, it gives me:

> CS0103: The name 'john_doe' does not exist in the current context

but when I simply create a html page and use the above code it works, it just doesn't work in razor view. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You can escape @ by writing @@ in razor

Comment: Or do `@{ var url = "..."; } <a href="@Html.Raw(url)">...</a>`

Comment: @Tarek, your suggestion did not work, but I appreciate the effort, upvoted you :)

Comment: @Peter, thanks buddy, if there was a way to accept your answer, would have done so. Your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the @ character in razor you can do that by using @@ instead. But that doesn't work all the time inside links despite the documentation.

Writing your link like this should work!

```
<a href="https://www.somegateway.com/@("@john_doe")/" class="im-checkout-btn btn--light" target="_blank" rel="modal">Checkout With someGateway</a>
```

Or

```
<a href="https://www.somegateway.com/@Html.Raw('@')john_doe/" class="im-checkout-btn btn--light" target="_blank" rel="modal">Checkout With someGateway</a>
```

If all else fails you could do

```
@{ var url = "https://www.somegateway.com/@john_doe/"; }
```

then

```
<a href="@url" class="im-checkout-btn btn--light" target="_blank" rel="modal">Checkout With someGateway</a>
```

Comment: Can you share the parent html tags of the anchor link?

Comment: @MichaelPhilips this should work:   <a href="https://www.somegateway.com/@("@john_doe")/" class="im-checkout-btn btn--light" target="_blank" rel="modal">Checkout With someGateway</a>

Answer (score 1):

You can put the url in a variable and then use that:

```
@{
    var url = "...";
}
<a href="@Html.Raw(url)">...</a>
```

Or even without the variable:

```
<a href="@Html.Raw("...")">...</a>
```